# Recommended way to re-arrange divs inside a container and save the new view

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, typescript

Now, I'm interested in the functions of drag and drop, where i can move my cards and charts around, and they should arrange themselves. This codepen example shows the functions i need to accomplish: 
`enter code here`https://codepen.io/therealDaze/pen/ZaoErp

relevant code for dynamically adding elements:

```
interface Config {
  id: string;
  measurement: string;
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

gaugeConfigs[]:Config=[];

addGauge(config:Config){
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var divbox = document.createElement("div");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    //some code regarding adding the gauge inside the box itself
    divbox.className = 'boxvalue';
    div.className = 'gauge-container normal';
    container.appendChild(divbox);
    divbox.appendChild(div);
 }
```

css for 'boxvalue' is

```
div.boxvalue {
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: rgb(248, 247, 247);
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
```

Now inside this div i add Gauge (from svg-gauge) and it shows my data like expected. Same way i do for charts (charts.js) and it also works. Note that chart container is bigger and sizes exactly like a 2x3 boxes of these gauges.

When i add items dynamically they are arranged as added. My main "container" can fit 2 charts next to each other on 1960x1080 resolution. That means 1 row of 6 gauges.

[image of correctly arranged divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtpsG.png)

If i add these randomly they aren't arranged and i would like to drag some around until they are in fitting order. I can do that by deleting some and re-adding them but that's not a good solution.

[image of incorrectly arranged divs - after deleting some order is lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq1sf.png)
Is there a better way to do drag and drop than the example? it functions just as i would like. Also what would be a good way to save the page appearance? Right now I have classes which hold the relevant information about created items (data it shows, min and max value, gauge color, etc). I serialize those classes and send them to sql database. 
When someone randomly connects to this application it reads this config, deserializes it and according to array of these classes it creates html elements. It was working perfectly this way until i had to add different sized Charts.
This is the function to load config from db and create all divs

```
  loadFromDb() {
    this.gaugeConfigs.length = 0; //reset the global configs array
    var observable = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Pages/Load');
    observable.subscribe(result => {
      if (result != null) {
        this.gaugeConfigs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        for (var i = 0; i < this.gaugeConfigs.length; i++) {
          this.addGauge(this.gaugeConfigs[i]);//calls the function for every class
        }
      }          
    });
  }
```

Hope i was clear enough

Comment: Typically, a long paragraph with no relevant code is not a good fit for stack overflow. You have shown no code to do drag and drop or to try saving/restoring its state. That is, you should not ask someone to write a solution, you need to write it on your own and if it doesn't work, then you post the code and we can help you figure out what went wrong. Drag/drop should be a separate question from saving/restoring state

Comment: I will add some code and pictures now

Comment: I would ask two new separate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you actually have two questions, we don't typically ask for suggestions

Comment: I'm not asking for the solution, I'm asking on idea how to extend my solution. Drag and drop was just part of the functionality for saving/loading state and hence i asked is that codepen good example. And I don't know how to explain my problem in shorter way since it builds on quite complex stuff.

Comment: I've narrowed it to two things: implementing drag and drop and saving/restoring states. Each question should be about one thing only, otherwise, it can't be easily searched. In asking for suggestions, there could be many valid correct answers, and we like questions that can have one accepted answer. If you try anything at all and pose two separate questions, you'll get the feedback you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Codepen JS and it's all DOM manipulation. I would create a Directive for this functionality or a contained component for reuse and within StackBlitz.

Angular wants us to use `ElementRef` to get reference to the DOM. Like this event listener (which you'll need).

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.eRef.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode.contains(event.target)) { 
        // click inside component
        this.active = true;
    } else { // click outside component
        this.active = false;
        this.arrow = -1; // reset
    }
}
...
constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {}
```

I've setup a StackBlitz [for my own reference that may help you and others here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hostlistener-dom-traversal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts).

The next thing is DOM manipulation; Renderer2 is recommended.
Here is a great [Alligator.io article for both methods](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/) combined.

Cool project, I'd love to see the outcome or help more if I can.

Comment: Looks good, I could use this, looks better than current code I have. How about saving the state? When i load data into page it goes through arrays and calls "addGauge" or "addChart" and appends the elements to container, so order in array is only order i have right now. Maybe I should ask a question on that, but it's all tightly connected